# DateTime change timezone without converting

Tags: c#

I am passed a `DateTime` object and a `string` timezone variable separately. Is there a way to cast this DateTime as the timezone in the string without "converting"(changing the actual time)?

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones

Answer (score 1):

If your time zone string is very specifically one of the system-defined strings, you can definitely do this.  The easiest way is to make the assumption that the DateTime passed in is already in UTC, and that the string passed in is one of the Id values listed in `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`.  Your function would look something like this:

```
public DateTime ConvertUtcDateTime(DateTime utcDateTime, string timeZoneId)
{
    var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
    var convertedDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, tz);

    return convertedDateTime;
}
```

This would create a "new" DateTime value, and your original utcDateTime value would be unchanged.  If you can't assume that the DateTime value is UTC, you'll have to require both the source and destination time zones and your function would change slightly:

```
public DateTime ConvertDateTime(DateTime currentDateTime, string sourceTimeZoneId, string destinationTimeZoneId)
{
    var tzSource = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(sourceTimeZoneId);
    var tzDestination = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(destinationTimeZoneId);
    var convertedDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentDateTime, tzSource, tzDestination);

    return convertedDateTime;
}
```

Keep in mind that in both of these functions, you need to test if the time zone returned by `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` is not null.  If it is, your input string was bad and you will need to handle that.  An exception would likely work well there, but I don't know your needs.

Edit:
As an afterthought, if your strings aren't exactly the same as the Id values from `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`, but they do kind of match up one-to-one, you could make some kind of `Dictionary<string, string>` to map your time zone strings to the system's Id values and run from that.  That's a good bit of hard-coding, though, but sometimes you need something like this if your inputs can't be changed.

Comment: The object is UTC but in reality its whatever timezone the user selects in the dropdown. The first solution, wouldn't that change the time value? And the second solution, can I pass source and destination both as the timezone the user selects? Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: In the first solution, you can convert whatever is selected in the dropdown into the appropriate timeZoneString by using the `Dictionary<string, string>` I suggested at the end.  As for changing the time value, it will not.  When you pass the DateTime into the function, you'll get a completely separate DateTime value back - they have no relation to each other and will remain separate values in memory.  For the second solution, passing the same timezone for each parameter will give you the same value that you put in to it and will effectively make the function do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` itself is immutable in C# so you can't really change it like you are wanting to.

Your best bet would be to store the object as a UTC DateTime and then based on the timezone string you are passed, add or subtract time from that to "correct" the UTC time stamp.

Comment: Seriously? So I would need to write my own convert function for every time zone and handle daylight savings myself simply because I can't create a datetime and specify timezone.. Seems kind of weird no ones had this issue where dashboard accepts a time and timezone. Should I tell all clients to enter UTC only lol?

Comment: @CodeHxr has a good answer for how to do the time zone conversions, or yes, you can force everything to be in UTC. Or you can combine the timezone info into it before you submit it. Why is it necessary to submit them seperately?

Comment: Users in India will be entering client deliveries for clients all over the world. Each client runs on different time zones. We use client time zones to communicate. So even though the user entering is on a India time zone, the actual date must be the client time zone. I am storing everything as UTC but I need to find a way to get the UTC. Then on read I convert to the client timezone.

Comment: Again, why is it being sent as two separate things though? Why not combine the two values before passing them? Is this a web app or a windows app or what?

Comment: so it's possible to instantiate datetime with specific timezone in JS but not C#? I prefer to store all conversions on server so we don't need to update all client facing apps

Comment: C# will convert a string representation of a date time in any valid format it understands pretty readily. "Wed, 03 Oct 2018 20:25:51 GMT" will parse just fine, as would "Wed, 03 Oct 2018 20:25:51 CST" but it would include the timezone offset

Comment: yeah I was just looking into that now. Yeah that's the solution I'm looking for! I can just DateTime.Parse(passedDate.Tostring() + timezone)

Answer (score 0):

Use UTC Time.

https://time.is/UTC

To implelent it, follow this code.

```
var currentDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: What if I want to cast this to eastern instead of cst?

Comment: You can get the CST and the UTC time and subtract the difference managing the result according to your needs.

Comment: It's for all time zones. So if the date is next year wouldn't using todays date difference be off for daylight savings?